# Skype SQLite DB empty and not sure how to read IndexedDB

Tags: 18.04, skype

I have Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Desktop and Skype 8.34.0.78 and there's /home/{user_name}/.config/skypeforlinux/databases/Databases.db that opens up in SQLiteStudio and I see the familiar table structure but there's no data in it at all.

So I searched for a string I recently used in Skype chat and found only one file containing it: /home/crewnew/Documents/IndexedDB/file__0.indexeddb.leveldb/000006.log but not sure how to read that file. SQLiteStudio can't open it and neither I can read it with my PHP code that I use to read Skype's main.db generated in Win10 machine:

```
$db = new SQLite3('skype.db');
$results = $db->query('SELECT nsp_data FROM messagesv12');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
// And here's the data:
// $messages['cuid']
// $messages['conversationId']
// $messages['creator']
// $messages['createdTime']
// $messages['content']
}
```

Basically I'm checking Skype db constantly if there are new messages in certain group chat and then send to MatterMost channel the messages but I had issues with WAMP server so I ended up installing Ubuntu and I love it in every way except the Skype DB issue. Maybe I should send Skype messages to MatterMost just in a different way?

Comment: `IndexedDB` isn't SQLite and isn't searched with SQL.  It also isn't a Relational Database like SQLite is.  Most of the documentation on how to interface with it I've found is JavaScript, unfortunately... [such as this tutorial shows](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_indexeddb.htm) or even [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB_in_chrome).

Comment: Thanks Thomas! So no SQLite in Linux Skype?

Comment: As Skype is **closed source** software, I don't have the information to answer you; the only way to determine if Skype still uses SQLite is to dissect the code or ask Microsoft yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb) of `/home/crewnew/Documents/IndexedDB/file__0.indexeddb.leveldb/` directly, it's just needed to implement a comparator named `idb_cmp1`.

Leveldb is a NoSQL key-value storage. For binary coded values of the db you can use my [python source](https://github.com/megabyte0/skype_leveldb) or [this C++ source](https://github.com/rtravis/SkypeCacheViewer) or implement the parsing directly in php, if you want, if it's possible to include leveldb into php somehow.

Note that from skype 8 the message history is stored in the cloud, you can read only cached ones from the leveldb. Enjoy.